# RVM: Create a gemset for whatever ruby is currently running

Tags: ruby, rvm

I want to use per project gemsets. But I don't want to specify the ruby version.

Something like:

```
#.rvmrc
   rvm --create use  "@project"
```

But this give me the following error:

```
error: Unknown ruby interpreter string component: 'ruby 1.9.2 p136'
info: Now using system ruby.
```

Is there a way to do what i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's the case but perhaps 
rvm --create use doesn't support params without ruby version.

```
#.rvmrc
rvm gemset create "project"
rvm gemset use "project"
```

I didn't check this, just saw at:
http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/creating/

Comment: Notice that my intention is to put that code in a .rvmrc file, so that a gemset is create and/or loaded automatically when I enter the directory. I tried you code but it just create the gemset, it does not load it.

Comment: This works:   rvm gemset create "akephalos"
rvm gemset use "akephalos"